# PDF reader with split screen feature?

Tags: windows, pdf-viewer

Is there a PDF viewer that supports split screen à la Word?

The following apps don't seem to:

- SumatraPDF
- Foxit Reader
- Acrobat Reader DC

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[PDF X-Change Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads) from Tracker Software Products will do exactly what you want.  You can split the screen horizontally or vertically, and adjust the split ratio at any time.

There is even a "spreadsheet split" mode, useful for examining pages that don't fit well on a single screen.

All of this functionality is available from the *View* ribbon.  Simply use the *Split* button on the *View* ribbon.

From personal experience, I can say that PDF X-Change Editor is a piece of very high quality software.  It is available as portable and installer-based software.

According to their website:

> More than 60% of the features in PDF-XChange Editor do not require a
>   license to use. The remaining features, which are clearly identified,
>   will place a 'trial' watermark on output if they are used without a
>   license.

Current licensing prices are available here: https://www.tracker-software.com/pdf-xchange-products-comparison-chart